# Unable to run a JBehave story

Tags: java, maven, jbehave

Can someone help me to run a JBehave story? I've got a Maven project in Eclipse.

The story is:

```
Meta:
@author Nikolay Vasilev
@bdd-talk: BG JUG

Scenario:  Validating BMI calculator

Given a body mass index calculator
When a doctor populates health record of a patient with mass 90 kg and 175 cm tall
Then patient's body mass index is 23
```

It is stored in `src/test/resources/stories`, which is reflected in the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/stories</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    ...
```

The steps class is:

```
public class MetricBMICalculatorSteps {
    private HealthRecord healthRecord;
    private MetricBMICalculator bmiCalculator;
    private BodyMassIndex bmi;

    @Given("a body mass index calculator")
    public void initBMICalculator() {
        bmiCalculator = new MetricBMICalculator();
    }

    @When("a doctor populates health record of a patient with mass $weight kg and $height cm tall")
    public void populateHealthRecord(@Named("weight") float weight, @Named("height") float height) {
        healthRecord = new ISUHealthRecord();
        healthRecord.setWeight(weight);
        healthRecord.setHeight(height);
        bmi = bmiCalculator.calculate(healthRecord);
    }

    @Then("Then patient's body mass index is $bmi")
    public void checkBmi(@Named("bmi") double bmiValue) {
        Assert.assertEquals(bmiValue, bmi.value());
    }
}
```

My Embedder is:

```
public class MyEmbedder extends Embedder {

    // --- Constants -----------------------------------------------------------

    private Configuration configuration;

    // --- Constructors --------------------------------------------------------

    public MyEmbedder() {
        configuration = loadConfiguration();
    }

    // --- Methods -------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return configuration;
    }

    // Here we specify the steps classes
    @Override
    public List<CandidateSteps> candidateSteps() {
        // varargs, can have more that one steps classes
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new MetricBMICalculatorSteps()).createCandidateSteps();
    }

    // --- Methods (Auxiliary) -------------------------------------------------

    private Configuration loadConfiguration() {
        Configuration configuration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();
        configuration.useStoryLoader(loadStoryLoader());
        configuration.useStoryReporterBuilder(loadStoryReporterBuilder());
        configuration.useStepMonitor(new SilentStepMonitor());

        return configuration;
    }

    // where to find the stories
    private StoryLoader loadStoryLoader() {
        return new LoadFromRelativeFile(
                CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()));
    }

    private StoryReporterBuilder loadStoryReporterBuilder() {
        // CONSOLE and TXT reporting
        StoryReporterBuilder storyReporterBuilder = new StoryReporterBuilder();
        storyReporterBuilder.withDefaultFormats();
        storyReporterBuilder.withFormats(Format.CONSOLE, Format.TXT);
        return storyReporterBuilder;
    }

    public void runStory(String story) {
        if (story != null && story.endsWith(".story")) {
            this.runStoriesAsPaths(Arrays.asList(story));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Problem locating .story file:" + story);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it with:

```
String storyRelativePath = "health/steps/MetricBMICalculator.story";
MyEmbedder eclipseEmbedder = new MyEmbedder(storyRelativePath);
eclipseEmbedder.runStory(storyRelativePath);
```

it seems to me that the steps file is not executed whatsoever (at least during debugging the execution doesn't stop on the breakpoints in the steps class which I put). Here is the output from the execution:

```
Processing system properties {}

(BeforeStories)
Using 1 threads
Running story health/steps/MetricBMICalculator.story

(AfterStories)
Generating reports view to 'D:\workspace\bg-jug-bdd\jug-bdd-jbehave-maven\target\jbehave'

using formats `[stats, console, txt]`

and view properties
{defaultFormats=stats, decorateNonHtml=true, viewDirectory=view, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl, navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl}
Reports view generated with 2 stories (of which 0 pending)  containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 failed and 0 pending)
```

Does anyone have a clue what I am supposed to do in order to run that story?

Answer (score 3):

Mauro Talevi answered this in [a mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@jbehave.codehaus.org/msg05272.html):

> You're missing the stats, which are used in the report generation.  You can 
>   either invoke `withDefaultFormats()` on the `StoryReporterBuilder`, or add 
>   `Format.STATS` directly to `withFormats()`.

Comment: in maven project, just create resources package under src/test and add all your stories in resources package.